# Making a jQuery dropdown box display inline

Tags: jquery, css, layout, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to use this jQuery plugin for a dropdown box.  I'd like the dropdown box to appear *next to* some text, rather than under it.  I've tried `float` and `display` properties and I feel like it's something really simple, but I just can't get it.

Demo: http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/examples/reinventing-drop-down/

CSS code in question:

```
    .desc { color:#6b6b6b;}
    .desc a {color:#0092dd;}

    .dropdown dd, .dropdown dt, .dropdown ul { margin:0px; padding:0px; }
    .dropdown dd { position:relative; }
    .dropdown a, .dropdown a:visited { color:#816c5b; text-decoration:none; outline:none;}
    .dropdown a:hover { color:#5d4617;}
    .dropdown dt a:hover, .dropdown dt a:focus { color:#5d4617; border: 1px solid #5d4617;}
    .dropdown dt a {background:#e4dfcb url(arrow.png) no-repeat scroll right center; display:block; padding-right:20px;
                    border:1px solid #d4ca9a; width:150px;}
    .dropdown dt a span {cursor:pointer; display:block; padding:5px;}
    .dropdown dd ul { background:#e4dfcb none repeat scroll 0 0; border:1px solid #d4ca9a; color:#C5C0B0; display:none;
                      left:0px; padding:5px 0px; position:absolute; top:2px; width:auto; min-width:170px; list-style:none;}
    .dropdown span.value { display:none;}
    .dropdown dd ul li a { padding:5px; display:block;}
    .dropdown dd ul li a:hover { background-color:#d0c9af;}

    .dropdown img.flag { border:none; vertical-align:middle; margin-left:10px; }
    .flagvisibility { display:none;}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Johnny, if any of the responses helped, could you select that response as the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us what you tried? First of all, format your code, you can use PHP to minify or minify only the live version (keep an unminified version for development)

Looking at that link, I'd say you need to apply float/display on dl.dropdown or .dropdown which I don't see in your code...

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, on the box that you click on, the `<dt>` box, make it have a style of `float: left`, also give a `float: left` to the `<dd>` containing all the selections.

Comment: you don't have to (or should not) add "float:left" to <dd>

Comment: Just tested it, adding `float: left` to just the `<dt>` resulted in a buggy layout that didn't display like OP wanted.

Comment: i'm using firefox 4.0.1 and it's working fine. guess it works differently in other browsers/systems.

Comment: Ahhh, that clears things up, chrome user here, to each their own.